# PHP cURL sitemap generator

Tags: php, curl, sitemap

Hi All I am having a problem with my sitemap generator it works great on a few thousand URLS but when it gets to 20000 URL it starts to go wrong is there anything else i can be doing to help prevent this

```
$request_url ="http://www.example.com";//put your url here
$url=str_replace("http://", "", $request_url); // i added this because to check if wwwdomain.com is in the url
$alllinks=array();// create an array for all the links
         $alllinks2=array();// create an array for all the links
          $alllinks3=array();// create an array for all the links
            $newUrl=array();// create an array for all the links
$badUrls=array("basket", "#" ,"mailto", "javascript:document", "reviews.php", "review.php","tab=",".JPG",".jpg","png","PNG","gif","GIF","item_id=","../", "pn_pr");// array of urls we dont want to include
$ch = curl_init(); //search for links
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 900);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Thank you

Comment: What does it mean "go wrong"?

Comment: Your code snippet does not access 20000 URLs, even if there are that many links inside the one page it accesses. Where is the full code that does the spidering/crawling?

Comment: Hi, it does not display the links, it works perfect for a few thousand links but 20000+ URLS seems to stop it, thank you

Comment: Sorry for not explaining better, the links are collected in an array and then all the links are followed and collected in another array and they are then followed, i just need a site map to go 3 links deep

Comment: is it possibly timing out? maybe check the max_execution_time php setting